# maven cargo deploy to war file fails to deploy as part of teamcity

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, ubuntu, teamcity

The same deployment works correctly on windows, and on linux - but using teamcity and its built in maven I get an error.  Local deploys, and the error  is :

> the container configuration directory
>   "/BuildAgent/work/68d4a71c8dc5cfd9/target/cargo/configurations/tomcat8x"
>   does not exist. Please configure the container before attempting to
>   perform any local deployment.

The relevant section of pom looks like this :

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <container>
                        <containerId>tomcat8x</containerId>
                        <home>${env.CATALINA_HOME}</home>
                    </container>
                    <configuration>
                        <type>existing</type>
                        <home>${env.CATALINA_HOME}</home>
                    </configuration>
                    <deployables>
                        <deployable>
                            <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ROOT</artifactId>
                            <type>war</type>
                            <properties>
                                <context>${project.build.finalName}</context>
                            </properties>
                        </deployable>
                    </deployables>
                    <deployer>
                        <type>installed</type>
                    </deployer>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Have I missed a section of the pom that is required for ubuntu ? Does teamcity do something different to vanilla maven ? I am using same version of maven in both environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your deploy work when you perform it on linux machine outside TeamCity?
Is `${env.CATALINA_HOME}` defined correctly?

My guess is that `${env.CATALINA_HOME}` is pointing to the wrong place

Comment: haven't had a chance to check this yet, but bounty on way it its this simple.

Comment: @NimChimpsky you cannot access throw ssh to the endpoint machine to check the value of the ${env} variable ?

Comment: I forgot to restart build agent, so new value of catalina_home was nto being picked up